# Android - How to make view pager right-to-left?

Tags: android-viewpager, right-to-left

I'm using this library : https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip and it works perfectly except that i want to add another language which is arabic so i want the tabs to swipe RTL and that every thing will be in reverse order.

I tried to set the Gravity of the tabs to right but it didn't work .. I also saw this library: https://github.com/dreamlearn/viewpager

but i don't know how to use it .. please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to reverse the order of the fragments
(when initialize them to the ViewPager) and do `viewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPagerSize)`.
But it's has to happen only if the locale is RTL so you have to use a method to determine if it is.

This is the code:

```
 public static boolean isRTL() {
    return isRTL(Locale.getDefault());
 }

 public static boolean isRTL(Locale locale) {
    final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(locale.getDisplayName().charAt(0));
    return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
            directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
 }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (isRTL()) {
        // The view has RTL layout
        adapter.addFragment(new S5(), getString(R.string.stage5));
        adapter.addFragment(new S4(), getString(R.string.stage4));
        adapter.addFragment(new S3(), getString(R.string.stage3));
        adapter.addFragment(new S2(), getString(R.string.stage2));
        adapter.addFragment(new S1(), getString(R.string.stage1));
    } else {
        // The view has LTR layout
        adapter.addFragment(new S1(), getString(R.string.stage1));
        adapter.addFragment(new S2(), getString(R.string.stage2));
        adapter.addFragment(new S3(), getString(R.string.stage3));
        adapter.addFragment(new S4(), getString(R.string.stage4));
        adapter.addFragment(new S5(), getString(R.string.stage5));
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And for the tabs you need to set the direction to LTR (It's looks messy when it's RTL).

So just used this code (It's only available in API 17+):

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
    }
```

I could'nt find a way to do this on pre API 17 **but you don't have to set the min SDK to 17**.

Comment: It actually does. As you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071342/how-to-create-rtl-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Hurray Android recently added new UI component called **ViewPager2 which supports RTL Layout**.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

- RTL (right-to-left) layout support
- Reliable Fragment support (including handling changes to the underlying Fragment collection)
- Dataset change animations (including DiffUtil support)
- Vertical orientation support

Below links talks about migration guide and sample app :

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2