# How to create RTL ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, right-to-left

I'm using ViewPager in my application and I want to support RTL, but when I cahnge my device language to RTl it seems it does'nt working.

I want the tabs to start from the right side (the first fragment in the right).

Please help me to solve it.

**EDIT**: Here is a picture of it:
[Tabs start from the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXcQt.png)

Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package ...;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Intro(), getString(R.string.Introduction));
    adapter.addFragment(new S1(), getString(R.string.stage1));
    adapter.addFragment(new S2(), getString(R.string.stage2));
    adapter.addFragment(new S3(), getString(R.string.stage3));
    adapter.addFragment(new S4(), getString(R.string.stage4));
    adapter.addFragment(new S5(), getString(R.string.stage5));
    adapter.addFragment(new S6(), getString(R.string.stage6));
    adapter.addFragment(new S7(), getString(R.string.stage7));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_contact_us: {
            Intent browserIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(getString(R.string.Contact_us_URL)));
            startActivity(browserIntent1);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_share: {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = getString(R.string.shareText);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getString(R.string.share_via)));
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_rate_us: {
            Intent browserIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(getString(R.string.Rate_us_URL)));
            startActivity(browserIntent2);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_help: {
            final Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent1);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_about_us: {
            final Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent2);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){

        case R.id.action_contact_us:
            Intent browserIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(getString(R.string.Contact_us_URL)));
            startActivity(browserIntent1);
            break;

        case R.id.action_share:
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = getString(R.string.shareText);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getString(R.string.share_via)));
            break;

        case R.id.action_rate_us:
            Intent browserIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(getString(R.string.Rate_us_URL)));
            startActivity(browserIntent2);
            break;

        case R.id.action_help:
            final Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpActivity.class);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent1);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.action_about_us:
            final Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                        startActivity(intent2);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

Thank you!!!

Comment: Check this android blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: Or you can use this library to achieve RTL ViewPager [https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager](https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager)

Comment: I did put android:supportsRtl="true" in the manifest

Comment: In this library the min sdk is 15 and main is 14.

Comment: this worked with me very good >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389545/11365488

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a lot of research I realized how to do it.
What I needed to do is to reverse the order of the fragments
(when initialize them to the ViewPager) and do `viewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPagerSize)`.
But it's has to happen only if the locale is RTL so I used a method to determine if it is.

This is the code:

```
 public static boolean isRTL() {
    return isRTL(Locale.getDefault());
 }

 public static boolean isRTL(Locale locale) {
    final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(locale.getDisplayName().charAt(0));
    return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
            directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
 }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    if (isRTL()) {
        // The view has RTL layout
        adapter.addFragment(new S7(), getString(R.string.stage7));
        adapter.addFragment(new S6(), getString(R.string.stage6));
        adapter.addFragment(new S5(), getString(R.string.stage5));
        adapter.addFragment(new S4(), getString(R.string.stage4));
        adapter.addFragment(new S3(), getString(R.string.stage3));
        adapter.addFragment(new S2(), getString(R.string.stage2));
        adapter.addFragment(new S1(), getString(R.string.stage1));
        adapter.addFragment(new Intro(), getString(R.string.Introduction));
    } else {
        // The view has LTR layout
        adapter.addFragment(new Intro(), getString(R.string.Introduction));
        adapter.addFragment(new S1(), getString(R.string.stage1));
        adapter.addFragment(new S2(), getString(R.string.stage2));
        adapter.addFragment(new S3(), getString(R.string.stage3));
        adapter.addFragment(new S4(), getString(R.string.stage4));
        adapter.addFragment(new S5(), getString(R.string.stage5));
        adapter.addFragment(new S6(), getString(R.string.stage6));
        adapter.addFragment(new S7(), getString(R.string.stage7));
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And for the tabs I had to set the direction to LTR (It's looks messy when it's RTL).

So I used this code (It's only available in API 17+):

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
    }
```

I could'nt find a way to do this on pre API 17.

Comment: I will be very thankful if you help me to do it on pre API 17.

Comment: Use `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(mTabLayout, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);` to support pre API 17.

Comment: As an alternative to setting the TabLayout direction in Java, you can also include `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` in your tabLayout xml block

Comment: The best answer was not convinced by rotation , thank you

Answer (score 16):

this library 
[RtlViewPager](https://github.com/duolingo/rtl-viewpager) Does the job cleanly

only requires replacing

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

with

```
<com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager
```

in the XML

it also supports tabLayout

using this approach is cleaner since it doesn't require reversing the Adapter logic

Also see this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56831) report for google

Comment: the library has problem with adding dynamic tabs

Comment: It's actually `<com.duolingo.open.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager>`

Answer (score 10):

My solution is adding  `android:rotationY="@integer/view_pager_rotation"`
**attribute** to `viewPager` in xml.

`values/integers` **contains** `<integer name="view_pager_rotation">0</integer>`

`values-ldrtl/integers` **contains** `<integer name="view_pager_rotation">180</integer>`

**Note** that the content is also get rotated.

## **Update 02/11/2019**

Now it's supported with [viewpager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) .

Comment: how about view pager indicators ??

Comment: @Kathi in my case I had no indicators

Comment: That's okay I am searching to do it so

Comment: fortunately by setting `android:rotationY="@integer/view_pager_rotation"` to View-pager-Indicator works great for me.

Comment: Content also get rotated

Comment: Nice solution, but you need to rotate the child container back to 180° with the same integer value. See answer of [Nauman Zubair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682144/2235073)

Comment: ViewPager2 is declared as final. Thank you google for best design as usual

Comment: Solution with view_pager_rotation constant is not working correctly for me. With this parameter page content are mirrored! It's very strange side effect.

Answer (score 8):

After a long research I found a very simple solution. Without reverse adapters, rotation child in their classes and etc.

```
open class RtlViewPager : ViewPager {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun onRtlPropertiesChanged(layoutDirection: Int) {
        super.onRtlPropertiesChanged(layoutDirection)
        if (layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            rotationY = 180f
        }
    }

    override fun onViewAdded(child: View?) {
        if (layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            child?.rotationY = 180f
        }
        super.onViewAdded(child)
    }

}
```

**Rewrite with Java :**

```
public class RtlViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public RtlViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RtlViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRtlPropertiesChanged(int layoutDirection) {
        super.onRtlPropertiesChanged(layoutDirection);
        if (layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            setRotationY(180f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        if (getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            child.setRotationY(180);
        }
        super.onViewAdded(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this library

https://github.com/duolingo/rtl-viewpager

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:<choose_your_version>'
implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you gave us , not only the ViewPager is not drawing itseft RTL, nothing is already RTL. How can be that if you set in the application tag supportsRtl="true" ?? You have to set RTL in the your phone Settings under Development options. If I am not wrong you have to set nothing to support RTL automatically in ViewPager
After getting your ViewPager propterly adjusted to RTL you can set which fragment you want to be the default fragment putting the following inside onCreate():

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(number)
```

where number indicates the number of the fragment in a zero based index. For example to select the first one, set 0, for the second set 1, and so on.

Comment: You right I updated it (the first image was taken from the emulator).

Comment: are your tabs not being reversed? I don't understand what you mean then

Comment: check the following library, it works with RTL:https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout , see the demo app for RTL example

Comment: Yes, the tabs aren't inverse

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(binding.pager, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another easy way to do so is by applying rotation to `ViewPager` and it's child view as follows:

**Step 1**. Change the rotation of the View pager

```
if(LocaleUtil.isRTL()) viewPager.setRotationY(180);
```

**Step 2**. Then again change the direction of the fragment container which is the child of `ViewPager`,

```
if(LocaleUtil.isRTL()) rootView.setRotationY(180);
```

In my case i had another fragment as child of view pager, so after inflating the layout i changed the direction of rootView.

**LocaleUtil.java**

```
public class LocaleUtil {

    // other functions

    public static boolean isRTL() {
        return isRTL(Locale.getDefault());
    }

    private static boolean isRTL(Locale locale) {
        final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(locale.getDisplayName().charAt(0));
        return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
            directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use ViewPager2 it has right-to-left(RTL) support and this will be enabled automatically based on app locale.

Answer (score 0):

No need of any third party library. Android recently added new UI component called **ViewPager2** which supports RTL Layout.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

Please find below link to an answer. The answer talks about Migration guide and sample github app to support RTL view pager.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558911/651377